# How to calculate and display a percentage in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to calculate a simple percentage, but the code below is not working unless the value is 100%. It shows .00% for all others.  Where am I going wrong?

```
<div th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal((summary.complete / summary.total) * 100, 1, 2)} + '%'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if you are using integers for `summary.complete` and `summary.total`. Integer arithmetic will result in an integer answer (hence zero or 100 for your percentage).

One quick way to fix that is to force at least one of the values to be a float, by adding `0.0` to it:

```
<div th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(((summary.complete + 0.0) / summary.total) * 100, 1, 2)} + '%'"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Thymeleaf `formatPercent` method for clarity and no need for the percent symbol or the multiplication of 100.  The multiplication of 1.0 will convert the integer to a float.

`${#numbers.formatPercent((summary.complete * 1.0/summary.total), 1, 2)}`

If your page allows for it, you could alternatively do the `summary.complete * 1.0/summary.total` on the server-side, unit test it there, and add the result to the model using `model.addAttribute(...)`.